# Prove $\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x^2-16}{x^2-4}=+\infty$

Tags: limits

How to prove?
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x^2-16}{x^2-4}=+\infty$$

from this definition 
$$ \forall {M>0}\;\exists {\delta>0}:\forall{x\in D},\,(0<x_0-x<\delta)\Rightarrow (f(x)>M)$$

I mean if is correct.

I have a problem with $\delta$ because I suppose it should be determined by depending on M but dont' know how to do that

Comment: XD There is an `automated-theorem-proving` tag?!  That is hilarious...

Comment: @SimpleArt: *automated* by *us*, I guess :D

Comment: In a left neighbourhood of $2$ the ratio $\frac{16-x^2}{2+x}$ is close to $3$. Can you prove that $$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{3}{2-x}=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{3}{z}=+\infty$$ through the $\epsilon/\delta$ definition? If so, you can also prove the given claim.

Comment: $\frac{x^2 - 16}{x^2 - 4}= \frac {x^2 -4}{x^2-4} - \frac {12}{x^2 -4}$  On the points where that *is* defined (all but $\pm 2$) that is $1 + \frac {12}{x^2 - 4}$.  So those two terms will have the same limit behavior.  Ans as we are approaching for $0< x < 2$ we will have $x^2 - 4 < 0$....

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok, this gets me $\delta=\frac{3}{M}$ and $\frac{3}{x-2}>M$ How make it $f(x)$ again?

Comment: @TheMeff: ask yourself: does this choice of $\delta=\delta(M)$ work also in the original limit / for the original function? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>4$ (for $0<M<4$, $\delta=1$ would suffice). Take $\delta=2(1-\sqrt{\frac{M-4}{M-1}})$. Let $x<2$ be such that $0<2-x<\delta$, or, in other words, $2>x>2\sqrt{\frac{M-4}{M-1}}$. It now easily follows
\begin{align}
x&>2\sqrt{\frac{M-4}{M-1}}\\
\sqrt{M-1}x&>2\sqrt{M-4}\\
(M-1)x^2&>4(M-4)\\
 M(x^2-4) &>x^2-16\\
\frac{x^2-16}{x^2-4} &> M
\end{align}

Which was to be proved.

Doing the last sequence of inequalities in reverse gives how $\delta$ was chosen.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

One of my math slogans:
Variables should approach zero.

So,
letting
$x = y+2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x^2-16}{x^2-4}
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{(y+2)^2-16}{(y+2)^2-4}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{y^2+4y+4-16}{y^2+4y+4-4}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{y^2+4y-12}{y^2+4y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{y^2+4y-12}{y(y+4)}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{-12}{4y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{-3}{y}\\
&= +\infty
\qquad\text{since } \lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{1}{y}=-\infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I don't understand where $\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{-12}{4y}$came from

Comment: As $y \to 0$, the numerator and $y+4$ go to non-zero values. Those are the values.